# ruby sequel access json field

Tags: ruby, json, postgresql, sequel

I have the following schema:

```
 Column  |            Type             |       Modifiers        
---------+-----------------------------+------------------------
 id      | text                        | not null
 data    | json                        | not null
 created | timestamp without time zone | not null default now()
```

If i open up psql i can run the query.

```
select id, data->'amount' as amount from plans;
```

But ruby `sequel` gem ruins it.

```
puts $db.run("select id, data->'amount' as amount from plans")
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed `#literal` method.

```
$db.run("select id, data -> #{ $db.literal('amount') } as amount from plans")
```